# Copy and paste bytes to clipboard with python

Tags: python, clipboard, ctypes

I'm trying to modify the clipboard byte contents, and so far I've managed to make a script that reads the clipboard as bytes:

```
import ctypes

CF_TEXT = 1

kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
kernel32.GlobalLock.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
kernel32.GlobalLock.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
kernel32.GlobalUnlock.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
user32.GetClipboardData.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

def get_clipboard_text():
    user32.OpenClipboard(0)
    try:
        if user32.IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_TEXT):
            data = user32.GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT)
            data_locked = kernel32.GlobalLock(data)
            text = ctypes.c_char_p(data_locked)
            value = text.value
            kernel32.GlobalUnlock(data_locked)
            return value
    finally:
        user32.CloseClipboard()

print(get_clipboard_text())
```

this script reads the clipboard and outputs something like this:

```
b'clipboard content here'
```

Now, I can't seem to find anywhere how to modify and  write it back to the clipboard using bytes, **pyperclip and many other modules I've tried use strings and has no way of using bytes**. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on Mac and I was looking for a cross-platform way to achieve this. After a day of research, I was able to find this library called `pyclip`.

```bash
$ python3 -m pip install pyclip # pyclip requires Python >=3.7
```

After installing `pyclip`, you can do stuff like this:

```py
>>> import pyclip
>>> with open('test.jpg', 'rb') as f1:
...    data1 = f1.read()
...
>>> pyclip.copy(data1)
>>> data2 = pyclip.paste() # returns bytes, paste(text=True) for str
>>> with open('test2.jpg', 'wb') as f2:
...    f2.write(data2)
...
6194
>>> data1 == data2
True
>>>
```

Here's the [PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/pyclip/) that includes the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example setting clipboard text, but note that CF_TEXT is ANSI text format and must be terminated by a null byte.  You can't send arbitrary byte data that contains nulls.  The example sends bytes 0x01-0xFF as a message and verifies that is what is returned from the clipboard.

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes as w

CF_TEXT = 1
GMEM_MOVEABLE = 2

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32',use_last_error=True)
kernel32.GlobalAlloc.argtypes = w.UINT,ctypes.c_size_t
kernel32.GlobalAlloc.restype = w.HGLOBAL
kernel32.GlobalLock.argtypes = w.HGLOBAL,
kernel32.GlobalLock.restype = w.LPVOID
kernel32.GlobalUnlock.argtypes = w.HGLOBAL,
kernel32.GlobalUnlock.restype = w.BOOL
kernel32.GetConsoleWindow.argtypes = ()
kernel32.GetConsoleWindow.restype = w.HWND
kernel32.RtlCopyMemory.argtypes = w.LPVOID,w.LPCVOID,ctypes.c_size_t
kernel32.RtlCopyMemory.restype = None

user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32',use_last_error=True)
user32.OpenClipboard.argtypes = w.HWND,
user32.OpenClipboard.restype = w.BOOL
user32.CloseClipboard.argtypes = ()
user32.CloseClipboard.restype = w.BOOL
user32.EmptyClipboard.argtypes = ()
user32.EmptyClipboard.restype = w.BOOL
user32.IsClipboardFormatAvailable.argtypes = w.UINT,
user32.IsClipboardFormatAvailable.restype = w.BOOL
user32.GetClipboardData.argtypes = w.UINT,
user32.GetClipboardData.restype = w.HANDLE
user32.SetClipboardData.argtypes = w.UINT,w.HANDLE
user32.SetClipboardData.restype = w.HANDLE
user32.GetActiveWindow.argtypes = ()
user32.GetActiveWindow.restype = w.HWND

def get_clipboard_text():
    user32.OpenClipboard(None)
    try:
        if user32.IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_TEXT):
            data = user32.GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT)
            data_locked = kernel32.GlobalLock(data)
            try:
                return ctypes.cast(data_locked,ctypes.c_char_p).value
            finally:
                kernel32.GlobalUnlock(data_locked)
    finally:
        user32.CloseClipboard()

def set_clipboard_text(message):
    user32.OpenClipboard(user32.GetActiveWindow() or kernel32.GetConsoleWindow())
    message += b'\0'
    try:
        user32.EmptyClipboard()
        h = kernel32.GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE,len(message))
        data = kernel32.GlobalLock(h)
        try:
            kernel32.RtlCopyMemory(data,(ctypes.c_char * len(message))(*message),len(message))
        finally:
            kernel32.GlobalUnlock(data)
        user32.SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT,h)
        if user32.IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_TEXT):
            data = user32.GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT)
            data_locked = kernel32.GlobalLock(data)
            text = ctypes.c_char_p(data_locked)
            value = text.value
            kernel32.GlobalUnlock(data_locked)
            return value
    finally:
        user32.CloseClipboard()

print(get_clipboard_text())  # prints whatever was on the clipboard beforehand
msg = bytes(range(1,256))    # can't send byte 0 except as null terminator for CF_TEXT
set_clipboard_text(msg)
msg2 = get_clipboard_text()
assert msg == msg2
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, this looks like exactly what I want but i get an error when i try to run it

Comment: @XCode I tested it.  What's the error?  Are you using an older version of Python?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jotje\Desktop\SNLT dev\SNL Internlenker\test.py", line 16, in <module>
    kernel32.RtlCopyMemory.argtypes = w.LPVOID,w.LPCVOID,ctypes.c_size_t
  File "C:\Users\jotje\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 382, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "C:\Users\jotje\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 387, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'RtlCopyMemory' not found

Comment: @XCode Strange, kernel32.dll has the function.  Windows 10 64-bit build 1903 is what I'm running on.  I just re-ran the code and it is working, but you can change it to use any memory copy routine.

Comment: Yes, I am testing on a quite cheap laptop but it is running windows 64 bit

Comment: @XCode From a VS command prompt, run "dumpbin /exports kernel32.dll | findstr Memory" and see what functions it lists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216702/discussion-between-mark-tolonen-and-xcode).